# StructureMap: How to use more than one concrete Class per Interface

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, structuremap

How can I figure StructureMap to use more than one concrete Class per Interface.
i.e. an IRepositoryCustomer is implemented by: RepositoryCustomerA and RepositoryCustomerB

How do I register and resolve this to/from the StructureMap IoC container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to answer the question, "when do I want RepositoryCustomerA instead of RepositoryCustomerB?"

If either of those classes could be instantiated in production based on some runtime state, then you probably want to look into [conditional object construction](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2009/01/18/conditional-object-construction-in-structuremap-i-e-fun-with-lambdas.aspx).

If RepositoryCustomerA should be instantiated at development time (for unit testing, say) while RepositoryCustomerB is the production analog, then you need two distinct `Registry`s: one that exists only in your test code, and one that is accessible in production.  For more on this route, read about [creating registries](http://structuremap.github.com/structuremap/RegistryDSL.htm) as a means of configuring StructureMap.

Comment: both variants seems to use strings. Is it possible to have this in a typesafe way?

Comment: I looked at the conditional object construction tutorial, but the methods that were used there are nearly all obsolete ... is there a current version for this? I use StructureMap 2.6.1.0

Comment: @Rookian: my apologies for missing your comments until now.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425565/structuremap-howto-conditional-construction-on-deep-object) might help you with avoiding the non-typesafe conditional constructions.  Registries support strings, but they aren't required in every case - it just depends on how much detail you need in your construction.  Just constructing one repository or the other sounds like it could be done in a typesafe manner.