# How to perform conditional binding in StructureMap from within a registry and without the use of generics?

Tags: dependency-injection, structuremap, ioc-container

I am familiar with Ninject and in Ninject you can do something similar to

```
Bind<ICalendar>().To<MonthCalendar>().WhenInjectedInto(typeof(Roster)).InRequestScope();
```

I'm not sure how to perform something similar in StructureMap. I need to be able to do this dynamically from my own binding without the use of the generic StructureMap methods. Additionally, I need to be able to do it from inside a Registry class. For example...

```
For(binding.Source).LifecycleIs(GetLifecycle(binding.Scope)).Use(binding.Destination);
```

I have looked at [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425565/structuremap-howto-conditional-construction-on-deep-object) and [codebetter](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/archive/2009/01/18/conditional-object-construction-in-structuremap-i-e-fun-with-lambdas.aspx) for ideas but can not work out how to do conditional binding as in the aforementioned Ninject example.

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret your Ninject configuration correctly - the generic solution in structure map would be:

```
For<Roster>().HttpContextScoped().Use<Roster>()
  .Ctor<ICalendar>().Is<MonthCalendar>();
```

---

**Edit:**

For doing the same thing with fully dynamic registrations instead you should be able to use this:

```
For(binding.Source).LifecycleIs(binding.Lifecycle)
  .Use(binding.Destination).Child(binding.ChildSource)
  .IsConcreteType(binding.ChildDestination);
```

---

For configuring a type registration dynamically you could use a convention:

```
public class DynamicConvention : IRegistrationConvention
{
        public void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
        {
            TypeRegistrationSettings typeSettings = FindTypeSettings(type);
            if (typeSettings == null)
                return;

            registry.For(typeSettings.Source)
              .LifecycleIs(typeSettings.Lifecycle).Use(typeSettings.Destination);
        }
}
```

Where FindTypeSettings(type) would look up your own bindings.

The convention is registered with a scan:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(
                c => 
                    c.Scan(s => {
                        s.TheCallingAssembly();
                        s.Convention<DynamicConvention>();
                    })
                );
```

Comment: Yes your first example was exactly what I was after except that I'd like to do it without generics and from within a registry class. Is this possible?As I load and process bindings in a Registry class I don't want to use a scanning method. There is no non-generic version of your first example available in StructureMap?

Comment: See my edit for a new shot on doing the same thing dynamically